# How to save HAR file using NetExport?

Tags: c#, selenium, firebug, netexport

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and C#, trying to see how this works.
I would like to save a JSON file and read it, but that's for a later part.

The HAR file NetExport is supposed to create is never saved.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
  profile.AddExtension("netExport-0.9b7.xpi");
  profile.AddExtension("firebug-2.0.7-fx.xpi");
  // profile.SetPreference("app.update.enabled", false);

  string domain = "extensions.firebug.";
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "currentVersion", "2.0.7");
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "allPagesActivation", "on");
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "defaultPanelName", "net");
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "net.enableSites", true);

  // Set default NetExport preferences
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.alwaysEnableAutoExport", true);
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.showPreview", false);
  profile.SetPreference(domain + "netexport.defaultLogDir",
      "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\HAR\\");
  IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);

  driver.Quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The reason is that exporting may take some time. Instead of waiting for a fixed period, place your `Sleep` into a loop like this (it's Java, but you can easily translate it to c#):

```
// Count files in output directory
final File harDir = new File(
     profile.getStringPreference("devtools.netmonitor.har.defaultLogDir", 
     "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Desktop\\HAR\\") );
final int numFiles = harDir.listFiles().length;

// Load test page
driver.get("https://ixquick.com");

// Wait up to 3 min for new file in output directory
for (int c=0; c<180; c++) {
    if (harDir.listFiles().length > numFiles) {
        break;
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
}
```